# .htaccess anti-hotlinking for one specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to prevent hot-linking of uploaded files with these extensions ( pdf|doc|docx|odt|rtf|txt ) for my website. Following is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(pdf|doc|docx|odt|rtf|txt)$ [R=302,L]    
</IfModule>
```

It is working for all website files. I want to implement it for one specific directory "my-uploads/my-directory".

I don't have enough knowledge about the .htaccess rules which condition I need to add. Please help me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this in your root's .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com/my-uploads/my-directory.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(pdf|doc|docx|odt|rtf|txt)$ [R=302,L]    
</IfModule>
```

Else, you can always add specific rules in an individual .htaccess inside that folder.